# Does Basic User Authentication require 2-Phase communiation?

Tags: http, boost, basic-authentication

My Application connects to the Internet to HTTP Services using boost::asio. Recently we added support for HTTP Proxys and Basic User Authentication. We implemented Basic User Authentication by just sending Authentication parameters with every HTTP call if a user configured a proxy in our program. Parameters are sent as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```
Authorization: Basic <base64 Encoded username:password>
```

This works at least for one user and his proxy server. Other users report that their Proxy server replys with

> 407 Proxy Authentication Required

My guess is that some proxy servers accept 1 one phase authentication and that others don't. I do not find any information that a 2 Phase communication is requested where the access always is denied for the first call by returning 407 and that only a second call is accepted.

Our program yet does not retry the call if a 407 has been returned. Do we have to add this?

Answer (score 2):

No, Basic Authentication does not require multiple requests.

That is, unless you first do the request without Authorization.

If the one proxy server doesn't accept the request /with/ the basic auth header, then perhaps it is configured with another authentication scheme (Digest Auth is common and arguably better).

You should probably inspect the full error message and/or contact the server admin to get more information. Alternatively, you can use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to inspect traffic from e.g. a browser that you *know* has no trouble connecting to the same proxy server.

Comment: Do you know any documents stating so? I looked in RFC1945 but i do not find specific information about that.

Comment: Mmm? RFC1945 just states that Basic Auth requires the header to be present. The server is free to respond with any error code as usual. There is not further protocol, outside passing the header. I think you're confusing the Proxy Auth with the web-server auth.

Comment: What do you think i am confusing? Is the authentication desiribed above not appropriate for a HTTP proxy?

Comment: The proxy requires separate authentication. 407 is not the same as 401

Comment: So whats the difference? How do you come up with 401? Do we have to send something different?

Comment: 401 is sent in response to rejected/missing Basic Auth (see rfc1945). 407 is sent by the proxy. See e.g. [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E407.html)

Comment: We are receiving 407. The sys admins confirm that Basic Authentication is enabled and that user/pwd parameters are correct. We tracked down that these are sent as described in the question. So from your point of view - is our communication correct?

Comment: BA is enabled /where/? I don't think I've ever seen a proxy using BA. I'm getting out of my depth here. I suggest asking on [SF.SE] or so ("How to transparent proxy Basic Authentication"?)